# How to validate data inside a csv or excel file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, sharepoint, file-upload

I currently have a mvc task to validate the data inside the csv or excel file before it uploads to sharepoint.
I need to validate the data such as phone number format and other types of data inside the uploaded csv or excel file.if the phone number format inside the file is not correct(ex: (985)-265-abcd) the file should not validate/upload and it has thorw validation error.

Is there any way to achieve that kind of functionality

Comment: can you please post some code that you have tried to make it working? How you are reading csv file content? One way is to read each line from the csv and then in each line split the values based on comma and then locate the column of the phone number and perform the validation on that..

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an event receiver that fires when the item is being added to the library.  At that point, you need to get your file, run the validation logic, and if validation fails, cancel the event to prevent the file from uploading.